# how to run a downloaded django project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I have gotten a django project from a colleague. After looking up how one should run it on their on computer, it seems I need to find a text file called "requirements.txt". However, I don't have this one in the folder that I've downloaded.

I tried running both commands

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but I get the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is
incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

running migrate before running runserver also doesn't help. It results into the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_extensions'
```

Can a downloaded django project be run without the requirements.txt file?

Comment: It will be very hard to install all pip dependencies without having a *requirements.txt* file in case of any Python project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pip install django-extensions
```

this should help

Comment: This is kind of *temporary solution*

Answer (score 0):

try to ask your colleague to initiate an environment using pipenv(pipenv shell) [after you install (pipenv) package with pip](https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide).that's going to create (Pipfile) --> which can be converted to requirements.txt or the other way around.
I highly recommend you to start using pipenv to handle your environment, it's absolutely a blessing.